# How to close a sqlite file opened with System.Data.SQLite and DbContext?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, sqlite, ado.net

In [my EF6 recreation](https://github.com/AArnott/ChinookSample) of [this walkthrough](http://www.bricelam.net/2012/10/entity-framework-on-sqlite.html) for creating and accessing a SQLite database using System.Data.SQLite, I found that any access to the database leaves the file handle open for the database file long after I've disposed of the only disposable object I created: the DbContext.

This prevents me from deleting the database file when I'm done with it (e.g. at the conclusion of a unit test, or when the user of my app requests it).

You can see how simple my use of `DbContext` is and how `File.Delete` after closing it fails:

```
using (var context = new ChinookContext())
{
    var artists = from a in context.Artists
                    where a.Name.StartsWith("A")
                    orderby a.Name
                    select a;

    foreach (var artist in artists)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(artist.Name);
    }
}

// I've disposed of the DbContext. All handles to the sqlite database file SHOULD
// have been released by now.
// Yet, this next line fails because the file is still locked.
File.Delete("Chinook_Sqlite_AutoIncrementPKs.sqlite");
```

([full project context on github](https://github.com/AArnott/ChinookSample/blob/master/Program.cs#L39))

Any ideas of what I'm missing in order to close the file handle?

BTW, I'm aware of [FAQ #22 on file locks](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q22) only being released when I dispose of command, data reader, etc., but I haven't opened any of these myself so I don't know how I can dispose of them.

Comment: Some answers to other, possibly related, questions suggest that forcing garbage collection using `GC.Collect();` before the delete call could be helpful. I haven't touched C# in a very long time so I can't say if it's correct, and maybe you've already tried it?

Comment: I just tried adding `GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` and that released the file handles. That suggests that either SQLite relies on GC and finalizers to release handles (which would be awful) or there is some object out there that I can actually reach in order to force deterministic disposal of. I hope it's the latter.